# Не подключается Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, прокрутка, плагин

Несколько часов пытался внедрить [Infinite Scroll](https://infinite-scroll.com/) в блоге. Цель простая, главная страница слишком длинная, хочется, чтобы она подгружалась постепенно. У авторов плагина есть идеально работающий [пример](https://infinite-scroll.com/demo/full-page/), однако, что бы я ни делал, в моём случае плагин соверешенно не срабатывает. Наверно, я что-то упускаю.

Если я правильно понял, то принцип работы плагина такой: мы создаём общий div и внутри него статьи (article). При заходе на страницу  человек видит 1 статью, когда прокурчивает до очередной статьи, страница увеличивается и отображается уже 2 статья и так далее. Вроде бы, это я и делаю.

Я пытался прикрепить его через ссылку

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/infinite-scroll@3/dist/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Пытался загрузить файл на сервер

```
<script src="js/infinite-scroll.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Пытался сами элементы оформить через jQuery, JavaScript и просто html, как и предлагается в документации, но всё безуспешно.

Ссылка на очень простую страницу сайта, где я пытался это реализовать: https://dinarkino.ru/new. На данный момент все параграфы загружаются разом, хотя каждый из них обёрнут в отдельный

```
<article class = "post"> ... </ article>
```

Буду очень рад помощи!

Comment: весь код в песочницу скиньте? если вы все правильно сделали, скорее всего может быть ошибка с подключением

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич вот весь код страницы: https://jsfiddle.net/dinarkino/pacovqb6/#&togetherjs=z4pg1Qq2ux
Немного изменил с момента создания вопроса, попытался как в примере разработчиков разделить одну страницу на несколько страниц с постепенной загрузкой каждой. Однако так или иначе страницы не грузятся

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Касательно изначального вопроса, у меня было неверное понимание механизма. Недостаточно просто создавать статьи (article) внутри div. Необходимо также делить страницу на несколько отдельных страниц и через pagination оформлять ссылки на следующие страницы. Таким образом, прокурчивая до конца страницы сробатывает ссылка на загрузку следующей страницы. Рабочий код первой страницы выглядит следующим образом:

```
<div class="posts-feed" data-infinite-scroll='{ "path": ".pagination__next", "append": ".post", "status": ".scroller-status", "hideNav": ".pagination"}'>
   <article class="post">
      <p>...</p>
   </article>
</div>
<div class="scroller-status">
    <div class="loader-ellips infinite-scroll-request">
      <span class="loader-ellips__dot"></span>
      <span class="loader-ellips__dot"></span>
      <span class="loader-ellips__dot"></span>
      <span class="loader-ellips__dot"></span>
    </div>
    <p class="scroller-status__message infinite-scroll-last">End of content</p>
    <p class="scroller-status__message infinite-scroll-error">No more pages to load</p>
  </div>

  <p class="pagination">
    <a class="pagination__next" href="https://dinarkino.ru/neww2">Next page</a>
  </p>
```

Где значимые составляющие: posts-feed, post, pagination

Далее сделав это, тем не менее, страницы не грузились. Проблема была в том, что ссылки вели на http версии страниц, а не https, на что ругался хром и блокировал загрузку. В dev tools была ошибка такого рода: *Mixed Content: The page at 'dinarkino.ru/new' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'dinarkino.ru/new2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*, после замены ссылок на такие, всё заработало:

```
href="https://dinarkino.ru/neww2"
```

Не знаю, хуже ли такие ссылки, чем ссылки на файлы на сервере, но пока попробую применить подобное на рабочей версии страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема у вас в том что вы внутри атрибута `data-infinite-scroll` вы написали двоичных кавычек внутри других двоичных кавичек

Ваш код

```
data-infinite-scroll="{ "path": ".pagination__next", 
"append": ".post", "status": ".scroller-status", "hideNav": ".pagination"}"
```

А надо так

```
 data-infinite-scroll='{ "path": ".pagination__next", 
    "append": ".post", "status": ".scroller-status", "hideNav": ".pagination"}'
```

Также этот атрибут должен добавлятся в класс `container`

Comment: Насколько я понял, есть разные способы подключения. В том числе через html код, как один из вариантов, который предлагают авторы плагина (https://infinite-scroll.com/, Initialize with HTML), я так и сделал
Через jQuery пробовал, как вы предлагаете.

Comment: @dinarkino надо конфигурацию написать к любому плагину нету того что вы проста написали html код и все заработало.Авторы предлагают использовать html + js.А у вас на сайте не было js подключений никакого кроме самого плагина.Я посмотрел может быть у вас конфиг написан в html внутри тега script и этого не было.

Comment: Ок, просто у них написано так: you can initialize Infinite Scroll in HTML, without writing any JavaScript. У меня сам плагин подключён через скрипт в head. Каким образом прописать конфигурацию?

Comment: @dinarkino да я прочитал эту  часть я упустил .Проблема у вас в другом .Сейчас я обновлью ответ.

Comment: @dinarkino посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: на момент с кавычками я тоже обратил внимание, в исходном коде у меня одинарные внешние. Через ctrl+U в хроме можно посмотреть, а через dev tools они двойными становятся. У авторов в примере такая же история

Comment: @dinarkino также добавьте атрибут data-infinite-scroll  к классу __container__

Comment: да нет, не в этом проблема. У меня к классу posts-feed прикреплен подобный атрибут. Проблему решил, не запускалось из-за ссылки без https, на что ругался хром. Чуть позже оформлю решение